# Dropna frunction works in Pycharm but throws error in Jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, jupyter

I am using dropna function to delete rows which  has null values in  a column.
the function works well in Pycharm and gives the result but the same code throws error in Jupyter notebook.

code used

```
data2 = data1.dropna(axis='rows', subset='TSeq_sequence')
```

Type Error

```
Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'TSeq_sequence' was passed
```

Comment: The dataframes must not be identical between programs. Use `df.info()` to start looking for possible differences.

Answer (score 0):

***subset*** argument needs to be List of Column Names (a Collection). You are passing a String value that looks like name of a List Sequence.

Reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html